# php table get value from button when clicked

Tags: php, jquery

i have this table with a button in it, what i want is when i click the button "id=myBtn" get its value to a input text field.

```
        <tbody>
                <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($queryTripulacion2)):? >
                    <tr>    
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="f[]" value=<?php echo $row[2];?>></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['order'];?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['name'];?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['last'];?></td>
                        <td  ><?php echo $row['cod1']?></td>
                        <td class="nr"><?php echo $row['cod2'];?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['address'];?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['activity'];?></td>

                        <td><input type="button" id="myBtn"  value="<?php echo $row['wanted_value']; ?>"></td>

                    </tr>
                <?php endwhile;?>
        </tbody>
```

this is what i tried, but is not working!. I want the "wanted_value" inside my "#inputM". THANKS!

```
        $(".tablar tbody").on('click','#myBtn',function() {

        $('#modal').show();

        var c = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.eq(8)').text();

        $("#inputM").val(c);
```

Comment: `.find('td.eq(11)')` is an invalid selector.  move the `.eq()` after the finder or use `:nth-child()`

Comment: changed to eq(8)

Comment: You're missing the point.  `.eq` is not a valid selector clause.  It's saying find `td` elements that have a class of `eq` and then errors on `(8)` which isn't valid selector syntax

Comment: IDs are supposed to be unique, you shouldn't have the same `id="myBtn"` in every row of the table.

Comment: Use a class instead.

Comment: If you want the value of the button you click on, why not just use `$(this).val()`?

Comment: Also, you don't use `.text()` to get the value of an input.

Answer (score 0):

`.eq()` is a function, not part of a selector. So it should be:

```
var c = $(this).closest('tr').find('td').eq(8).text();
```

But this won't work. That TD doesn't have any text in it, it just has the input button. You need to select the button, not the TD, and use `.val()` rather than `.text()`.

```
var c = $(this).closest('tr').find('td').eq(8).children(":button").val();
```

But this is all really overcomplicating it, since the button you're selecting is the same one you clicked on, so it should just be:

```
var c = $(this).val();
```